# Insert String to NSTextField from NSTable Row

Tags: swift, nstableview, nstextfield

I want to insert the string from double clicked row in NSTabeView at cursor location in NSTextField. The following code works (row text is retrieved) but is not inserting the text into the textfield:

```
@IBAction func pickParameterFromTable(_ sender: NSTableView) {

    let tableRow = sender.clickedRow

    let pickedParameter = nameArray[tableRow]
    print(pickedParameter)
    if let currentEditor = equationTextField.currentEditor() {
        currentEditor.insertText(pickedParameter)
    }
}
```

When double click on table row NSTextfield is not selected anymore (cursor is disappearing). Similar code works with using NSButtons instead of NSTableView as sender.
Thanks!

Comment: When you click on the table view, the focus moves to the table view. The text field isn't focused anymore and doesn't have a field editor.

Comment: @Willeke, thanks for the respond. I guessed as much already. Do you have a hint how to get the focus to the text field again? Using first responder doesn't work somehow. I searched on how to get focus on textfield but without any luck so far.

Comment: I searched too but didn't find a good answer. Use `makeFirstResponder` of `NSWindow` to make the text field first responder.

Comment: @Willeke, thanks. I'll check that out.

Comment: @Willeke, since I'm still to stupid to understand the whole responder chain and using it right not to mention I just took your advice and manipulate the string leaving the focus on the tableview. I just update the string with replacing the range selected by the new substring: `string = string.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: pickedParameter)`